# Finding and replacing a dynamically created string in Twig?

Tags: replace, twig, craftcms

There is a product URL that is defined in a field in craft cms.

I need to replace the http with https using Twig

I'm using the find and replace method but am not seeing any changes.
Have tried putting the find and replace

```
 {% set productlUrlUpdate = "http://address" %}
 {% set productUrlUpdate = productUrlUpdate|replace({'http://address' : https://address'}) %}
```

Before and after the definition of `productUrl` without seeing anychanges in the `<img>` when rendered to the browser

```
{% set productUrl = entry['productUrl'] is defined and entry.productUrl is not empty
? entry.productUrl
%}


 {% set productlUrlUpdate = "http://address" %}
 {% set productUrlUpdate = productUrlUpdate|replace({'http://address' :
'https://address'}) %}


<img src="{{ productlUrl }}" width="1" height="1">
```

Can someone explain to me where I am going wrong please

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you even doing this? If you've changed from http to https you'd be better off just updating the database with the change rather than processing the URL's on every load.

Comment: @RickCalder It's an easier / quicker solution - I'm just doing what I've been told ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact you don't see any changes lays in the fact you are doing the replace on the (non-existing) variable `productUrlUpdate`, instead of the variable you are outputting (`productUrl`)

You should just do

`<img src="{{ productlUrl | replace({'http://':'//',}) }}" width="1" height="1">`